# Let $A=k[x]$ and let $V=k[x]/\big((x-λ )^{n} \big)$ for some $λ \in k$ and $n\in \Bbb{N}$. Then $V$ is indecomposable.

Tags: representation-theory

**Theorem.** *Let $A=k[x]$ and let $V=k[x]/\big((x-\lambda )^{n} \big)$ be a representation of $A$ for some $\lambda \in k$ and $n\in \Bbb{N}$. Then $V$ is indecomposable.*

This is a theorem in my book. But I don't get their first line of reasoning:

> It suffices to show that any proper subrepresentation $U\subset V$ is contained in $I:=\overline{(x-\lambda )}$.

Why does it suffice to prove that ? I get that this means that $I$ is proper submodule then, but how does that make $V$ indecomposable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if $V$ was not indecomposable? Then it would be decomposable, i.e. there existed proper subrepresentations $U$ and $U'$ with $V=U\oplus U'$. But if we prove that all proper submodules are contained in $I$ we get the contradiction that also $U\oplus U'$ is a subrepresentation of $I$.

Comment: Wait a second, basicly are you saying that if $U,U'$ are contained in $I$, then $U \oplus U'$ must also be contained in $I$, right? That sounds weird to me. Couldn't I show using that reasoning that $I \oplus I$ , must be contained in $I$.

Comment: $I\oplus I$ is not an internal direct sum, it has a non-trivial intersection.

Comment: I don't see why you should take the internal direct sum. I thought that the direct sum of representations (definition 2.3.7) $V_1,V_2$ was about the external direct sum. Otherwise, many direct sums of representations would be undefined right ?

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable with the internal direct sum, just replace it with the ordinary sum: $U+U':= \{u+u': u\in U, u'\in U'\}$. The argument woks just as fine.

Comment: Thanks, in that way it makes sense. Still trying to make sure I feel more comfortable with direct sums. So if I understand correctly, the internal and external direct sums are isomorphic. But $I\oplus I$ seems to be defined as external direct sum, but not as internal direct sum, which confuses me. I would think that $I \oplus I = I^2$ as external direct sum, but undefined as internal direct sum.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I get it. Thanks for your help !